# On maximal subgroup's index of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime. Assume that for every maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$ we have $[G:M]$ is not $\equiv1$ mod $p$. Prove that $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. Furthermore, if $M$ ia a maximal subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:M]\equiv0$ mod $p$, prove that $[G:M]$ is a power of $p$.

Please tell me some hints since I have no idea.

Comment: Do you see how to show the second part once you have shown that $G$ has a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Not yet. Please help me

Comment: I have not thought much about the first part, but for the last part, look at $PM$ where $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: May you tell me some more hints?

Comment: What will the index of $PM$ be?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between $PM$ and $[G:M]$.

Comment: Please take a bit longer to think about it then.

Comment: $P \in Syl_p(M)$ or $P \in Syl_p(G)$?

Comment: A $p$-Sylow of $G$

Comment: Can you explain to me why must study $PM$?

Comment: Well, what will the index of that subgroup be?

Comment: It's a power of $p$, right?

Comment: How could it be? It contains a $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part, let P be a Sylow p-subgroup. Then M can not contain P for p divides |G:M|. And G=MP for M is maximal and P is normal. Now $ |G:M|=|P:P\cap M| $ is power of p.

Answer (score 5):

For the first part, use [Sylow theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).

If $P$ is a non-normal $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, then $N_{G}(P)$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing  $N_{G}(P)$.

Both $\lvert G : N_{G}(P) \rvert$ and $\lvert M : N_{M}(P) \rvert = \lvert M : N_{G}(P) \rvert$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $p$.

Comment: Can you explain more precise? For the first part, how should I use Sylow 's theorem?

Comment: @user109584 In the way he explained in the rest of the answer.

Comment: Ehm, of course. He used proof by contradiction.

Comment: How about the second part?

Comment: @user109584 I already gave you some hints on that. The ball is in your court on those.

Comment: @Caranti: +1 vote Thank you very much

Comment: @user109584,you're welcome